# Can't insert "<" when writing message with Gnus after enable BBDB

Tags: gnus, bbdb

I enable `BBDB` as below

```
  (el-get-bundle! bbdb
    (defun ec--bbdb-initialize ()
      (flyspell-mode t)
      (bbdb-initialize 'message)
      (bbdb-initialize 'gnus)
      (local-set-key "<TAB>" 'bbdb-complete-name))

    (add-hook 'message-mode-hook #'ec--bbdb-initialize)
    )
```

When I try to write message in `Gnus` after press `a` in a group. I can't insert `<` char. Because it is define as `Prefix Command`. But I can't find where it is defined in `BBDB` package.

The reason I think it is the issue related to `BBDB` is when I comments the code above in my config file, I can insert `<` char and it is not show as `Prefix Command` in `describe-bindings`.

Doesn't anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Doesn't `C-h k <` (`describe-key` `<`) tell what it's bound to?

Comment: `<` is bound as a prefix command. You can't get the description for `prefix command`. `C-h b` can list the bind. But I how to find where it is bind and how to unbind it.

Answer (score 1):

You can pretty much always insert any character using `C-q`: `C-q <`. I'd be surprised if that didn't work in your context. (Of course, often there is an easier, more direct way to insert a given character.)

Comment: That works and I can insert `<`. But I really hope to find where it is bound and how to unbind it.

Comment: Check `bbdb-mode-map` (or whatever the map is called - you might need to check more than one map). If you use library [**`help-fns+.el`**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/help-fns%2b.el) then you can use `C-h M-k`, entering the map-variable name, to see a human-readable list of the keys in that map.